# Google Sheets Programs on Mobile App

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-sheets

I have the following code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var task = ss.getRange(2,4).getValue(); //ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
var who = Session.getActiveUser();
var date = new Date();

function start() {
var last = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(last+1, 1).setValue(task);
  ss.getRange(last+1, 2).setValue(who);
  ss.getRange(last+1, 3).setValue(date);
}


function end() {
var last = ss.getLastRow();


  ss.getRange(last, 4).setValue(date);
  ss.getRange(1,1).setValue(date);
  ss.getRange(1,2).setValue(ss.getRange(last+1, 3));

}
```

in a Google Sheet script. It works on desktop - basically what it does is it will track when a user starts and stops a given task.

The sheet shows up fine in the Sheets app, but the script doesn't run. What needs to happen so that it will run? Is there some way to run the programs on the app?

Comment: They are tied to a button press. I've uploaded a PNG to the sheet with the word "START" in the middle and one with "STOP" in the middle. Start is tied to the start function, STOP is tied to the end function.

Comment: I found this https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-a-Google-Apps-Script-spreadsheet-on-a-mobile-phone but it seems that when I'm trying to press it on my phone the picture is selected, rather than starting the script.

Comment: The pictures are showing up on mobile. The clicking of the pictures does not seem to do anything.

Comment: See [Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87346)